# Scroll event firing too early

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have on my website two fixed headers; one of them is being covered by another - unless you scroll all the way to the colored section, where the top one should get clipped and reveal the one on the bottom:

```js
    let invertedNavbar = document.querySelector('.navbar--inverted'),
      navbarHeight = invertedNavbar.scrollHeight,
      element = document.querySelector('.color-section')

    function intersectionChecker(e) {
        let elementPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect()
        if (elementPosition.bottom < navbarHeight && elementPosition.bottom > 0) {
          invertedNavbar.style.clipPath = 'polygon( 0% 1000px, 100% 1000px, 100% ' + elementPosition.bottom + 'px, 0% ' + elementPosition.bottom + 'px)'
        }
        if (elementPosition.top > 0 && elementPosition.top < navbarHeight) {
          invertedNavbar.style.clipPath = 'polygon( 0% 0px, 100% 0px, 100% ' + elementPosition.top + 'px, 0% ' + elementPosition.top + 'px)'
        }
        if (elementPosition.top < 0 && elementPosition.bottom > navbarHeight) {
          invertedNavbar.style.clipPath = 'polygon( 0% -10px, 0% -10px, 0% -20px, 0% -20px )'
        }
    }
    intersectionChecker()

    window.addEventListener('scroll', intersectionChecker)
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar{
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
}
.navbar--inverted{
  background-color: blue;
}

.spacer{
  height: 100vh;
}

.color-section{
  background-color: orange;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar"></div>
<div class="navbar navbar--inverted"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="color-section"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

Now, it works pretty well - except when you scroll out of the section, the navbar is being left with some clipping. It seems that a scroll event is being fired before actual scroll ends.

I tried some different options - defering checking of the position with `requestAnimationFrame` (gave no results at all, even tried to wait two frames, no change at all for some reason); defering with `setTimeout 100` - it worked quite well, but also made the whole thing look pretty laggy; doubling the check conditions, that is turning them to `elementPosition.bottom < 2 * navbarHeight && elementPosition.bottom > -navbarHeight` - which works relatively well, but is unelegant and not entirely foolproof, the user can still scroll too fast for it to catch it. Do you have any ideas how to improve on it?

Comment: "Works pretty well" -> don't want to criticize, when you scroll very fast, it doesn't work that well.. Also, what do you mean exactly by "scroll out of the section"?

Comment: @Kaddath You mean that it's lagging? It's very possibly because this is only a minimal test case without defering and so on that I have in my actual code. And by scroll out of section I mean when the navbar stops intersecting the colored section.

Comment: why are you calling your function `intersectionChecker()`

Comment: No, i mean when i scroll very fast up and down all the way, the header is always red or the blue one ends almost completely covered by th red one (Firefox on windows here)

Comment: @Kaddath That's exactly my problem

Comment: @MaheerAli A leftover from a previous idea where I actually wanted to use an intersectionObserver, didn't bother to change the name of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually we were mislead by the question to think that the problem came from the moment the events were fired, it was not.. It was simply a problem with your conditions! The part remaining in the clipping was because for example when scroll reached 0, no change in the style was triggered because of strict `>` comparisons.

Don't know if all of them are necessary, but changing them to `>=` and `<=` partly solved the problem.

Also needed to add a case for when the element was completely lower than the navbar:

```js
    let invertedNavbar = document.querySelector('.navbar--inverted'),
      navbarHeight = invertedNavbar.scrollHeight,
      element = document.querySelector('.color-section')

    function intersectionChecker(e) {
        let elementPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect()
        if (elementPosition.top > navbarHeight) {
          invertedNavbar.style.clipPath = ''
        }else{
          if (elementPosition.bottom <= navbarHeight && elementPosition.bottom >= 0) {
            invertedNavbar.style.clipPath = 'polygon( 0% 1000px, 100% 1000px, 100% ' + elementPosition.bottom + 'px, 0% ' + elementPosition.bottom + 'px)'
          }
          if (elementPosition.top >= 0 && elementPosition.top <= navbarHeight) {
            invertedNavbar.style.clipPath = 'polygon( 0% 0px, 100% 0px, 100% ' + elementPosition.top + 'px, 0% ' + elementPosition.top + 'px)'
          }
          if (elementPosition.top <= 0 && elementPosition.bottom >= navbarHeight) {
            invertedNavbar.style.clipPath = 'polygon( 0% -10px, 0% -10px, 0% -20px, 0% -20px )'
          }
        }
    }
    intersectionChecker()

    window.addEventListener('scroll', intersectionChecker)
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar{
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
}
.navbar--inverted{
  background-color: blue;
}

.spacer{
  height: 100vh;
}

.color-section{
  background-color: orange;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar"></div>
<div class="navbar navbar--inverted"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="color-section"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
```